# Why the JoomShopping plug-in does not work?

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0

Sorry for my bad english, but I really need to know why this plugin does not work at all.

So i have Joomla 3.5.1 + JoomShopping 4.14.1

I want to connect the attributes filter plugin. But it does not work.

Help me please!!!

```
<?php

// No direct access.
defined('_JEXEC') or die;


class plgJShoppingOxboxAttribsFilter extends JPlugin
{
    public function __construct(&$subject, $config)
    {
        parent::__construct($subject, $config);
    }


    public function onBeforeQueryCountProductList($controller, &$adv_result, &$adv_from, &$adv_query, &$order_query, &$filters = array())
    {
        $this->onBeforeQueryGetProductList($controller, &$adv_result, &$adv_from, &$adv_query, &$order_query, &$filters);
    }


    public function onBeforeQueryGetProductList($controller, &$adv_result, &$adv_from, &$adv_query, &$order_query, &$filters = array())
    {
        // Ïîëó÷àåì îáúåêò áàçû äàííûõ
        $db = JFactory::getDBO();
        // 
        $query = $db->getQuery(true);
        // 
        $query->select('params');
        //
        $query->from('#__modules');
        //
        $query->where('module = "mod_oxbox_jshopping_attribute_filter"');
        //
        $query->where('published = 1');
        //
        $db->setQuery($query);
        //
        $list = $db->loadObjectList();
        //
        if (is_array($list) && count($list))
        {
            //
            foreach ($list as $item)
            {
                //
                $registry = new JRegistry();
                //
                $registry->loadString($item->params);
                // 
                $item->params = $registry->toArray();
                // Ïîëó÷àåì çíà÷åíèå
                $vals = JRequest::getVar($item->params->get('param_name'), '');
                //
                $vals = urldecode($vals);
                // Åñëè çíà÷åíèå íå ïóñòîå
                if (!empty($vals))
                {
                    // Åñëè ñîäåðæèò òî÷êó ñ çàïÿòîé
                    if (JString::strpos($vals, ';'))
                    {
                        // Ïðåîáðàçóåì â ìàññèâ
                        $vals = explode(';', $vals);
                    }
                    // Åñëè â ìàññèâå òîëüêî îäèí ýëåìåíò
                    if (is_array($vals) && count($vals) == 1)
                    {
                        //
                        $vals = $vals[1];
                    }
                    // 
                    $attr_id = $item->params->get('attr_id');
                    // 
                    $db->setQuery('SELECT independent FROM #__jshopping_attr WHERE attr_id = '.$attr_id);
                    // Ïîëó÷àåì ðåçóëüòàò
                    $independent = $db->loadResult();
                    // Åñëè àòðèáóò íåçàâèñèìûé
                    if ($independent)
                    {
                        $table = '#__jshopping_products_attr2';
                        $attr_value_id_field = 'attr_value_id';
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $table = '#__jshopping_products_attr';
                        $attr_value_id_field = 'attr_'.$attr_id;
                    }
                    // Åñëè ôèëüòðóåì ïî çíà÷åíèÿì àòðèáóòîâ
                    if ($item->params->get('param_type', 'value') == 'value')
                    {
                        // Åñëè ýòî ìàññèâ
                        if (is_array($vals))
                        {
                            $adv_query .= 'AND prod.product_id IN (SELECT product_id FROM `'.$table.'` AS attr LEFT JOIN #__jshopping_attr_values AS attr_values ON attr_values.value_id = attr.'.$attr_value_id_field.' WHERE `name_ru-RU` in ('.implode(',', $vals).'))';
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $adv_query .= 'AND prod.product_id IN (SELECT product_id FROM `'.$table.'` AS attr LEFT JOIN #__jshopping_attr_values AS attr_values ON attr_values.value_id = attr.'.$attr_value_id_field.' WHERE `name_ru-RU`="'.$vals.'")';
                        }
                    }
                    else // èíà÷å ôèëüòðóåì ïî èäåíòèôèêàòîðàì çíà÷åíèé àòðèáóòîâ
                    {
                        // Åñëè ýòî ìàññèâ
                        if (is_array($vals))
                        {
                            $adv_query .= ' AND prod.product_id IN (SELECT product_id FROM `'.$table.'` AS attr WHERE attr.'.$attr_value_id_field.' in ('.implode(',', $vals).'))';
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $adv_query .= ' AND prod.product_id IN (SELECT attr.product_id FROM `'.$table.'` AS attr WHERE attr.'.$attr_value_id_field.' = '.$vals.')';
                        }                       
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: does not work **HOW**? wrong results? crashes your server? Kicks your dog?

Comment: white screen and this error:
`Fatal error: Call-time pass-by-reference has been removed in ... on line 17`
this code:
`$this->onBeforeQueryGetProductList($controller, $adv_result, $adv_from, $adv_query, $order_query, $filters);`
If i replace &$ to $ i get new error:
`Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object in ... on line 52`
this line: 
`$vals = JRequest::getVar($item->params->get('param_name'), '');`